# flowplayer with 302 redirect as video file

Tags: redirect, jwplayer, http-status-code-302

I am trying to get JW Player to take the file source as a 302 redirect.

For example

```
  <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        jwplayer("myElement").setup({

            file: "http://release.theplatform.com/content.select?pid=wDDAdred_zKoOybAKvsfHai8DNT1zHhg&UserName=Unknown" type="video/mp4",

        });

    </script>
```

The redirect appears to be working fine however the player is not playing the video.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be using the JW Player with a redirect like this, you just need to change a bit of code.

Under this line:

```
file: "http://release.theplatform.com/content.select?pid=wDDAdred_zKoOybAKvsfHai8DNT1zHhg&UserName=Unknown" type="video/mp4",
```

Add:

```
type: "mp4"
```

That should do the trick.

You also do need to make sure that the file is encoded in H.264.

I tried to test out your redirect URL, but I got the following "Access Denied" message:

```
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://dev6.content2.video.news.com.au/txM2thOTquWY8V3sFImEr2rPxFVGOLdh/DOcJ-FxaFrRg4gtDEwOmtrOjBrO9IBkc?" on this server.

Reference #18.e04503f.1360681662.1f1248c7
```